# Continued fraction of square root of $k^2-8$

Tags: number-theory

Good day!
I want to know if there is a periodic Continued Fraction for $\sqrt{k^2-8}$ where $k$ is odd greater than or equal to $5$? It just fascinated me for a month and unfortunately I couldn't find it. I hope you could answer! Thanks!

Comment: Well, yes, there is. Any square root has a periodic continued fraction. Don't know how to find that specific one, though.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange Theorem. Every quadratic irrational has a PCF. Since sqrt(k^2-8) is irrational w may say that it has PCF.